# Variable with enum datatype and not all values within contains value?

Tags: c#, enums

I have variable allowedPlaceOfWork with datatype:

```
[Flags]
public enum PlaceOfWOrk {
  CompanyOffice = 1 << 0;
  ClientOffice  = 1 << 1,
  HomeOffice    = 1 << 2,
....
}
```

and contains values:
`ClientOffice` and `HomeOffice`.

Also, I have `Employee` entity with `place of work` within, how can I check if employees `place of work` in allowedPlaceOfWork?

I've tried to use `Enum.IsDefined` but it works with all enum, I have just some values of it.
Also, I have an idea to convert it to `IEnumerable` and check values within the collection but in this case, I have to convert from enum to collection.

Is there any way to check it without converting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless I am misunderstanding you can do

```
Employee.PlaceOfWork.HasFlag(allowedPlaceOfWork)
```

Comment: I'm sorry but if I understand the variable names correctly that would check if the current employees place of work conforms to all of the allowed places of work... Shouldn't it be reversed?

Comment: but i didnt think what if data will be changed from outside